# ssh -X on mac gives error in matlplotlib

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, ssh, matplotlib

I'm trying to ssh into a server and run a python script on it.

I keep getting the error when I run the command on a mac.

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 443, in clf
gcf().clf()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 369, in gcf
return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in            new_figure_manager
  window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1688, in __init__
  self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
  _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

---

I'm using ssh -X abc@xyz.com to ssh. This works without any problem on ubuntu but gives this  error on mac. I have just shifted to mac and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have XQuartz installed?  `$DISPLAY` should be automatically set on OS X to a launchd socket which will automatically launch XQuartz when accessed.  A common mistake is setting `$DISPLAY` to :0.0, but I think that would cause a different error.

Here's how things should look:

```
% echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-k9XueA/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Comment: It prints nothing when I do a $DISPLAY. I'm doing this on my MAC and not on the server.

Comment: @Kakashi The Mac native GUI is not X windows. You need a X server for remote display. Ubuntu native GUI is X Windows, so it works there.

Comment: @Kakashi Like Nicholas said, you probably need XQuartz installed. Do you have that installed?

Comment: It worked after installing Xquartz. I think it was because they removed X11 from OSX in mountain lion.